# ColdFusion - String to variable

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

I have a string like this that I get from a database:

```
user=me@example.com&name=John
```

I'd like to know if there is an easy way to extract the data and put them into two variables, user and name.

Comment: You can use Regex or look into `SpanExcluding` paired with other string functions.  https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/spanexcluding.html

Comment: Treat the string as nested lists.  The outer list would be delimited by the `&` character and the inner one by the `=` character.

Comment: Since this is apparently a URL parameter string, are you encoding or sanitizing it before you insert into the database? Or is it stored just like above?

Comment: What @Shawn said. This is a very easy way for someone to attack your site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Marc, As per @Dan Bracuk suggestion you can split your string by using mentioned delimeter first as `&` and again as `=`. Please refer my below code that will help you. I hope.

[Runnable Example](https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=8d04fc42-66a2-4f02-8d12-0718a5bce24d/ca237178-c3cc-4fe8-9473-f630b2119cbe/6f7c5e17-71bf-42ac-83e0-2fd47f6d76bb.cfm)

```
<cfset yourInput= 'user=me@example.com&name=John'>
<!--- Get the first value. I mean "user" part --->
<cfset splitFirstPart = listfirst(yourInput,'&', true)>
<cfset splitLastPart = listlast(yourInput, '&', true)>
<!--- Get the second part value --->
<!--- Above values are split by using & --->
<cfset user = listlast(splitFirstPart, '=', true)>
<Cfset name = listlast(splitLastPart, '=', true)>
<!--- 
    Now we can again split the list by using =. 
    Now you can see the result.
--->
<cfoutput>
    User : #user# <br/>
    Name : #name#
</cfoutput>
```

If you need any other CFML functions & clarification please refer https://cfdocs.org/

Thanks.

Comment: One thing to watch out for is that `listLast()` will return the *first* element if the parameter value is empty. For example `&name=(blank)`.  To make the code more robust, consider using the `getToken()` function instead. @MarcElBichon - Also, you could easily turn the code above into a reusable function that splits any query string and returns a structure of parameters and values

Comment: Yes @ageax. Then you can use includeEmptyValues attribute in listlast (). For example 
listlast(splitFirstPart,'=',true). Then it's will return the user = '' (empty) only. Please check that.

Comment: True. Most list functions didn't support that attribute for so long, I keep forgetting they finally "fixed" them!  Hope you don't mind I added your suggestion to the code above, since there's a good chance url parameters could be empty :-)  If you don't like it, feel free to roll it back.

Comment: I hope all the list functions support includeEmptyValues attribute. Especially listfirst & last support. I cross check that. Thanks for your changes on my comments. @ageax.

Comment: I didn't check all of them, but it looks like most of them do (now). So good tip.

Comment: Thanks for your time @Ageax

Answer (score 3):

Here is my take on how to solve this one.

I like having a structure as final result. I also like working with the each functions as an implicit loop.

```
<cfscript>
yourInput= 'user=me@example.com&name=John';

variables.result = {};
ListEach(yourInput,
   function(item) { variables.result[listfirst(item, "=")] = listLast(item, "="); },
   "&");

writedump(result);
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Nice and succint. Only improvement I'd suggest is using `includeEmptyElements=true`, in case the value is empty, so the list functions don't return the "name" instead of the "value".

Answer (score 2):

To add to this answer for future readers, there are a couple of ways to make this more dynamic.

Essentially, you are just parsing a delimited list twice and pulling out the pieces you need. ColdFusion allows several ways to do that.

For illustration, I've added to the original string.

```
string="user=me@example.com&name=John&somethingelse=42&foo&base64Msg=QmVFeGNlbGxlbnRUb0VhY2hPdGhlcg==" ;
```

My preferred way to parse this is to us a CF function that returns a struct of all of the pieces I need.

```
public Struct function parseURLParamString( required String inURLStr ) {
    /// Initialize the return struct.
    var retStruct = {} ;
    // Use listEach() function to iterate over the list with delim "&"
    arguments.inURLStr.listeach( 
        function(item){ 
          // listFirst gets 1st list element. listRest() gets all but 1st element. Delim "="
          retStruct[listFirst(item,"=")] = listRest(item,"=") ; 
        }
        , "&"
    ) ;

    return retStruct ;
}

writeDump( parseURLParamString(string) ) ;
```

This will return:

[image: code1]

Then you can just reference the variables you need from your returned struct.

But if you need to create actual variables instead of pulling them from a struct, you can do so like this:

```
arguments.inURLStr.listeach( 
    function(item){ 
      variables[listFirst(item,'=')] = listRest(item,"=") ;
    }
    , "&"
) ;
```

... and then change your outer function to either return `Void` or nothing and drop the struct from it. You can reference the variables like `user = #user#`. This would require you to know the variables in advance, whereas when passing a specific struct, you can just loop over the struct and output the keys/values. Technically you can also loop over the `variables` scope, but there will likely be a lot of other variables in there, too.

If you want, you can also use `getToken()`, but it has the same limitation that `listLast()` does. If your `value` contains the second delimiter text (like a padded Base64 string), then those characters would be treated as a delimiter and be left off of your value. For `base64Msg = QmVFeGNlbGxlbnRUb0VhY2hPdGhlcg==`, `getToken()`/`listLast()` will return `QmVFeGNlbGxlbnRUb0VhY2hPdGhlcg`, where `listRest()` will give you `QmVFeGNlbGxlbnRUb0VhY2hPdGhlcg==`. Or even worse, if the character is in the middle of the string, it will be truncated. `ListLast()` removes the first item of a delimited list and returns the rest of the list, so if your string contains the delimiter, it will return the full value.

Lastly, since this appears to be a string from a URL, you probably want to sanitize and encode the string before you store it in the database.

If you save the encoded value, it will likely turn your delimiters into their encoded values. The above frunctions only support single-character delimiters, so wouldn't be usable as above (unless decoding before sending to the splitting function). `listToArray` allows multi-character delimiters. So that may be one way to split them.

In the end, there are a lot of characters that are allowed a URL string, `#` and `=` being two that are sure to cause you issues without encoding and proper handling.

Comment: Good catch! Base64 encoded values. Yet another gotcha.

Answer (score 1):

You could use "ListToArray" using "&" as delimiter to split each value, and then use again (or use ListFirst and ListLast if there is only 2 values) but this time using "=" as delimiter, that way you will have ["user=me@example.com", "name=John"] as First result, and [[[user],[me@example.com]],[[name],[John]]] as second.

I usualy recomend use structs instead of simple variables, here goes one example

```
<cfscript>
    /* My Raw string */
    MyString = "user=me@example.com&name=John";

    /* Breaking my single string in multiple values */
    MyArrayOfValues = ListToArray(MyString, "&");

    /* Creating my struct o hold my values */
    MyStruct = StructNew();

    /* Interating over my values */
    for (Value in MyArrayOfValues){
        // First Interaction will be: user=me@example.com and the second will be name=John and etc...
        /* Get My attribute name */
        MyAttributeName = ListFirst(Value, "=");
        /* Get My attribute value */
        MyAttributeValue = ListLast(Value, "=");
        /* Evaluate the values of you borth variables and asign each other */
        Evaluate("MyStruct.#LCase(MyAttributeName)# = '#MyAttributeValue#'");
    }
    /* Here you can see your value printed as struct formed by 2 atributes, name and user, both in lower case */
    writeDump(MyStruct);

    /* Here one example how to use this data */
    writeOutput("
        Hi my name is #MyStruct.name# and my user is #MyStruct.user#!
    ");
</cfscript>
```

This way is more generic approach, since you probabily will have more columns in your database or even can use it with other data from another data base, always following the same struct... values seperated by & and attribute and value by =

Comment: My vote just put your reputation into quadruple digits.  You owe me a beer.

Comment: No need for evaluate though. Just use structure notation. Also, don't forget to account for empty parameters with the list functions.

Comment: The thing is, the values from database are dynamic, so he wont be able to know if use this algorithm in multiple databases... because of that im using Evaluate, i dont thing just use somethine like (MyStruct.#SomeValue#) going to work about, probabily will prompt Sintax error